# Ruby-on-rails: are there any other way to make page statefull except use session?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I am creating search form for model with some tabs, radiobuttons, dropbox, etc. I use `index` action for searching and sorting. Parameters for searching is persisted in params. It works while I stay in the same `index` view. But if I had to visit other page and then come back to search page again, params doesn't work and state is not persisted.

I know I can do it with session, but suppose I would have more search forms for another models and so all that params goes into session. Doesn't it make session messy?

**So question is:**
Is there other reasonable way to persist page state (but I don't want to put into database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider a class in your app to help manage data input/output, somewhat similar to ActiveRecord's database interface.  You can store this data either in a session maybe memcache or redis server would be better.  Here's an example.

```
class SearchParam

  def initialize(id, model, query_string = nil)
    @id = id
    @model = model
    @query_string = query_string
  end

  def save
    # write @query_string to redis using `key`
  end

  def self.find(id, model)
    instance = new(id, model)
    instance.query_string = Redis.get(instance.key) 
    return instance
  end

  def query_string
    @query_string
  end

  def query_string=(qstring)
    @query_string=qstring
  end

  def key
    "#{@id}-#{model}"
  end

end
```

I forget the exact redis commands and syntax, but you'll get the idea if you've worked with it before - basic writing and reading.  Memcache or session would also work.  Then you can easily store the hash representation of the query string for a user/model combo and set your search params for use in the search form.

Easy to lookup based on a session id in the controller when they first get to the index page (if there are no params submitted)

```
@search_params = SearchParam.find(session.id, model).query_string
```

Or to save the new query_string when you return results based on the form submit in the index action

```
SearchParam.new(session.id, model, params).save
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also localStorage (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) available in browser, but you have to use JS to access it.

Otherwise, I think it is okay to store it in session, unless you have like tens of different search forms.